# unable to set state using expo-image-picker

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to allow a user to select an image from gallery, then pass the image to the next screen as a parameter where they can finish their post (Similar to instagram create flow).

Using expo image picker, the button can be clicked which opens the gallery, and allows the user to select an image, and the gallery closes. This is done using this code:

```
async openImagePickerAsync() {
    let permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestCameraRollPermissionsAsync();

    if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
      alert("Permission to access camera roll is required!");
      return;
    }

    let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync()

    console.log(pickerResult.uri)
    
    if (pickerResult.cancelled === true) {
        return;
    }

    this.setPicked(pickerResult);
};
```

The console logs the uri, everything is great. The picture is selected. The problem begins in the this.setPicked function call, where I am simply confirming a picture was selected and setting the state:

```
setPicked = (pickerResult) => {
    console.log("called setPicked")

    if (pickerResult !== null) {
        console.log("pickerResult not null")
        this.setState({
            image: pickerResult.uri
        }).bind(this)
        console.log(pickerResult.uri)
        console.log(this.state.image)
     }
     else {
        console.log("pickerResult is null")
         return;
     }
}
```

None of the print statements are printing, and I get this warning in the console:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.setPicked')]
```

Any idea what is going on? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the  openImagePickerAsync function doenst have access to 'this'

change it to an arrow function like below and it should work.

```
 openImagePickerAsync = async ()=> {
```

Comment: Well you need to bind this or use an arrow function to get access to the context, refer this https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/